# Grails table-per-subclass inheritance and discriminator

Tags: grails, inheritance, grails-orm, hibernate-criteria

I am using Domain inheritance in grails App with

> tablePerHierarchy false

So i get one big table with common properties and for each subclasses tables with specific columns to them only.
So let say relation is like below

```
A -> B
A -> C
A -> D -> E
A -> F -> G
```

where A is parent class. Now i need to find all B,D,E and need to have paged results on that. I was trying to write criteria query but as **no discriminator support is there**. Can anyone help me out on the same?

I have tried to use following criteria query and found one strange thing.

```
A.createCriteria().list(max:max,offset:offset) {
            eq("isDeleted", false)
             inList('class', [1,3])
}
```

It worked for me but one strange thing. How would i identify which class is referring to value 1 as discriminator and which to value 2?
I am on Grails 2.4.2

Comment: why are you using `[1,3]` instead of `[ 'A', 'C' ]`? should work just fine

Comment: It does throw Class cast exception. Can't cast String into Integer. Even i have logged the sql query. It does give class field as calculative field in the sql query, which assign number if data present in the join table.

Comment: `case when this_2_.id is not null then 2 when this_4_.id is not null then 4 when this_6_.id is not null then 6 when this_1_.id is not null then 1 when this_3_.id is not null then 3 when this_5_.id is not null then 5 when this_.ID is not null then 0 end as clazz_2_`

Comment: ok I see. try using `sqlRestriction 'class in ( 'A', 'B' )'`. in this case no `case` clauses are generated

Comment: But I am using Table per sub-class where no class field does exist only through joins it does identify which class that row represents. :(

Comment: right, sorry! I misread that